# How do I leverage my JS file with HTML in TWIG

Tags: javascript, drupal, twig, drupal-8

I have the following JS that needs to be loaded into a Twig Template.

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

var handle


var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal and begin countdown
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  (function(){
    var countdown = 5;

    handle = setInterval(function() {
      countdown--;
      if (countdown >= 0) {
        span = document.getElementById("countdown");
        span.innerHTML = countdown;
      }
      // Display 'counter' wherever you want to display it.
      if (countdown === 0) {
        window.location.href= 'http://www.google.com';
        clearInterval(handle);
      }

    }, 1000);

  })();

}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
  clearInterval(handle);
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    clearInterval(handle);
  }
}
```

I want to put it in this file:

```
{{ attach_library('/popup_external') }}

{% set header = content.field_header_text_external %}
{% set link = content.field_external_quote_link %}
{% set phone = content.field_text_html_phone %}
{% set popup %}
HTML HERE
{% endset %}
```

This is for Drupal, but I cannot seem to get the HTML there to ever display as actual HTML rather just plain text, even if I use {{ popup|raw }}

What am I missing that would help me get this JS into the twig file more easily??

Comment: how do i leverage the other variables then?

Comment: does not make sense. Twig does not escape static values